# Control suggestions that function like a multi column listBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've looked at a bunch of different controls(ListView, GridView, etc.) and can't decide which makes the most sense for me to use.

I want something that looks and functions just like a listBox with the ability to select a row with a single click, except it would contain data with multiple columns.

I'm just looking for suggestions on which control to use and how I would go about having it select a row(whether it's a selectionMode or an onClick function or what). Since I'm new to these controls I'd like some direction on which tag to place those selection options, I think I can figure out the rest however.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using the ListView that contains a GridView as it's view.  Here's how I defined it in XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lstCurrentInvoices" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionMode="Extended" ToolTip="Invoices included in invoice file." IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="8">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width="40" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientId}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Width="170" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientName}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding InvoiceDate}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Width="40" Header="Frequency" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Frequency}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This way you kind of get the best of both worlds.  In this example, you can have multiple rows selected.  You can detect which rows have been selected and grab the objects from you data source.  It's really quite powerful.  Hope this helps

Comment: That looks nice and simple, I'm not using XAML but I might be able to convert that fairly easily. Thanks :)